# How to change Vite dev server asset base path

Tags: laravel, docker, vite

I'm running a Vite dev server in a Docker container and trying to load assets from that Vite server in a Laravel Blade template with the @vite directive, but the @vite directive is outputting the assets at `http://127.0.0.1:5173/path/to/asset` or `http://[::]:5173/path/to/asset`. I want to test the website on a different computer from the server, on the same network. And if I do that, of course the assets won't load because they're only accessible to the server computer itself.

I see that the @vite directive gets its base path from a `public/hot` file generated by the Vite dev server at runtime, but I can't for the life of me figure out how the hot file gets generated or what determines its output. I'm assuming surely there must be a configuration option, but I've tried every config and environment variable I can find, and nothing ever affects the hot file, even after restarting and rebuilding the vite docker container.

docker-compose.yml

```
...

vite:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: vite/Dockerfile
    image: me/vite
    container_name: appvite
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
      - "8000:8000"
    working_dir: /app/
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    networks:
      - app-network

...
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig(({ command }) => {
    const config = { plugins: [], server: {} };
    if (command === 'serve') {
        // Dev specific configs
        config.plugins.push(
            laravel({
                input: ['resources/js/app.js'],
                refresh: true,
            })
        );
        config.server.origin = "http://test1";
        config.origin = "http://test2";
        config.base = "http://test3";
        config.server.base = "http://test4";
    } else {
        // Build specific configs
        config.plugins.push(
            laravel({
                input: ['resources/js/app.js'],
                refresh: false
            })
        );
    }

    return config;
});
```

vite/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 5173
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev-debug"]
```

.env

```
...

ASSET_URL=http://test1
VITE_ASSET_URL=http://test2

...
```

Comment: what happend if instead of http://test2 put your machine Ip and vite port.

like if your IP is : 192.168.1.150,  assets should be visible on IP:PORT/path/to/asset.
if  you want to test in your computer try 0.0.0.0 instead of IP.

Comment: The assets are indeed visible at `IP:PORT/path/to/asset`, but the @vite Blade directive is not outputting the HTML to correctly reference the assets at that address. Instead it's using `LOOPBACK:PORT/path/to/asset`

Answer (score 0):

just change .env

```
ASSET_URL=MACHINE_IP:VITE_PORT
```

like: `192.168.1.150:5173`

it should work.

Based on [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#custom-base-urls)

Comment: I suspect that only works for fully built assets rather than the Vite dev server, because based on the Laravel vendor code, it looks like the base path always relies on the contents of the `public/hot` file generated by the dev server, if said server is running. And that hot file always contains a loopback address instead of the one configured in the ASSET_URL env variable.

Comment: @user2536496 could  you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855929/a-way-to-run-vite-dev-on-remote-server-like-laravel-mix