# Remote server + Laravel Vite HMR blank screen

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-vite

I have an issue working with Laravel 10 and Vite on remote server. I use VS Code and SFTP Extension to sync my project between local and remote server. It works great. My Vite DEV server is also running on remote machine. I edit `blade` templates from my VS Code, and it successfully transfered via SFTP protocol to remote server. Vite DEV server uses HMR to watch this changes. But, when autoreload occured, sometimes, I see a blank page on my screen instead of rendered template.

My vite config:

```
import { build, defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'MY_IP',
        }
    },
    build: {
        sourcemap: 'hidden',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
                    let extType = assetInfo.name.split('.').at(1);
                    if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(extType)) {
                    extType = 'images';
                    } else if (/woff|woff2|otf|eot|ttf/.test(extType)) {
                        extType = "fonts";
                    }
                    return `assets/${extType}/[name]-[hash][extname]`;
                },
                chunkFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
                entryFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
        inject({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        }),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/scss/styles.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ]
});
```

Vite DEV server is launched with command `vite --debug --host`.

Logs from DEV server on `blade` template saving:

```
  11:09:20 AM [vite] page reload resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php (x6)
      vite:hmr [no modules matched] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +1ms
      vite:hmr [file change] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +91ms
    11:09:20 AM [vite] page reload resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php (x7)
      vite:hmr [no modules matched] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +2ms
      vite:cache [304] /@vite/client +10s
      vite:time 0.63ms /@vite/client +10s
      vite:cache [304] /resources/scss/styles.scss?direct +22ms
      vite:time 0.42ms /resources/scss/styles.scss +22ms       
      vite:cache [304] /resources/js/app.js +1ms
      vite:time 0.27ms /resources/js/app.js +1ms
      vite:time 0.21ms /resources/images/logo.png +2ms
      vite:time 0.14ms /resources/images/notification.svg +0ms       
      vite:time 0.15ms /resources/images/notifications_ok.svg +1ms   
      vite:cache [304] /node_modules/vite/dist/client/env.mjs +5ms   
      vite:time 0.23ms /node_modules/vite/dist/client/env.mjs +3ms   
      vite:time 0.21ms /resources/images/notifications_info.svg +16ms
      vite:time 0.15ms /resources/images/notifications_error.svg +3ms
      vite:time 0.24ms /resources/images/burger.svg +4ms
      vite:time 0.16ms /resources/images/icon-nav_buy.svg +0ms
      vite:time 0.17ms /resources/images/icon-nav_export.svg +2ms
      vite:time 0.27ms /resources/images/icon-nav_stats.svg +15ms
      vite:time 0.14ms /resources/images/icon-nav_api.svg +2ms
      vite:time 0.19ms /resources/images/stats_green.svg +3ms
      vite:time 0.19ms /resources/images/stats_red.svg +5ms
      vite:time 0.22ms /resources/images/stats_blue.svg +2ms
      vite:time 0.17ms /resources/images/stats_yellow.svg +1ms
      vite:time 0.18ms /resources/images/arrow_black.svg +11ms
      vite:time 0.16ms /resources/images/ok.svg +4ms
      vite:time 0.15ms /resources/images/del.svg +2ms
      vite:time 0.17ms /resources/images/file-csv.svg +5ms
      vite:time 0.28ms /resources/images/filter.svg +6ms
      vite:time 0.16ms /resources/images/arrow.svg +1ms
      vite:cache [304] /resources/js/scripts.js +133ms
      vite:time 0.58ms /resources/js/scripts.js +50ms
      vite:time 0.27ms /resources/images/icon-nav_buy-active.svg +58ms
      vite:hmr [file change] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +7s
    11:09:28 AM [vite] page reload resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php (x8)
      vite:hmr [no modules matched] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +1ms
      vite:hmr [file change] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +55ms
    11:09:28 AM [vite] page reload resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php (x9)
      vite:hmr [no modules matched] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +0ms
      vite:cache [304] /@vite/client +9s
      vite:time 0.47ms /@vite/client +9s
      vite:cache [304] /resources/scss/styles.scss?direct +1ms    
      vite:time 0.38ms /resources/scss/styles.scss +1ms
      vite:time 0.19ms /resources/images/logo.png +1ms
      vite:time 0.15ms /resources/images/notification.svg +1ms    
      vite:time 0.20ms /resources/images/notifications_ok.svg +0ms
      vite:cache [304] /resources/js/app.js +22ms
      vite:time 0.59ms /resources/js/app.js +21ms
      vite:time 0.30ms /resources/images/notifications_info.svg +13ms
      vite:time 0.15ms /resources/images/notifications_error.svg +1ms
      vite:time 0.14ms /resources/images/burger.svg +1ms
      vite:time 0.15ms /resources/images/icon-nav_buy.svg +0ms
      vite:cache [304] /node_modules/vite/dist/client/env.mjs +24ms
      vite:time 0.42ms /node_modules/vite/dist/client/env.mjs +8ms
      vite:time 0.48ms /resources/images/filter.svg +25ms
      vite:time 0.16ms /resources/images/stats_yellow.svg +1ms
      vite:time 0.21ms /resources/images/arrow.svg +4ms
      vite:time 0.21ms /resources/images/stats_blue.svg +3ms
      vite:time 0.22ms /resources/images/icon-nav_stats.svg +0ms
      vite:time 0.21ms /resources/images/stats_green.svg +1ms
      vite:time 0.34ms /resources/images/icon-nav_api.svg +16ms
      vite:time 0.25ms /resources/images/file-csv.svg +1ms
      vite:time 0.21ms /resources/images/stats_red.svg +2ms
      vite:time 0.41ms /resources/images/icon-nav_export.svg +7ms
      vite:time 0.17ms /resources/images/arrow_black.svg +0ms
      vite:time 0.14ms /resources/images/ok.svg +2ms
      vite:time 0.24ms /resources/images/del.svg +16ms
      vite:cache [304] /resources/js/scripts.js +133ms
      vite:time 0.48ms /resources/js/scripts.js +55ms
      vite:time 0.23ms /resources/images/icon-nav_buy-active.svg +72ms
      vite:hmr [file change] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +11s
    11:09:39 AM [vite] page reload resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php (x10)
      vite:hmr [no modules matched] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +1ms
      vite:hmr [file change] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +265ms
    11:09:39 AM [vite] page reload resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php (x11)
      vite:hmr [no modules matched] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +2ms
      vite:hmr [file change] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +88ms
    11:09:39 AM [vite] page reload resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php (x12)
      vite:hmr [no modules matched] resources/views/trader_add/index.blade.php +2ms
```

As you can see, at the and of log, my edited page is reloading multiple times by Vite DEV server. I think that it is the main reason for problem. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the vite assets are not loaded because the website script and css links to localhost instead of an accessible host on the network. I had the same issue and was able to resolve it with the instructions here, answer by Neo:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76666874/22132679

Comment: My scripts and HMR are connected to remote host, as you can see from my code. When I edit directly file on remote, it works perfectly. But when I work from VS Code and sync my edited file from locale to remote on save, it gives a blank screen. I think, that vite tries to watch this file, at least, 2 times. So it reload twice my page and I see a blank page.

Comment: Oh sounds like a race condition, that is a tricky one, would be hard to troubleshoot on here unless you get lucky and someone else has had the same issue and figured it out. I am not sure how your setup works, I never have had a setup that I edit files on remove that would require Vite. As much as VSCode has become the default for most people including myself, I have A LOT of issue like this with it and its extensions.

Comment: I don't know how you're syncing with VSCode on a remote, I've never personally used that functionality but I am inclined to think your issue is that the mechanism is not compatible with how Laravel and Vite are programmed to work and a not a problem with their configuration. I think if you dig in Vite settings you might find some compatibility configuration for delays and such perhaps. Good luck